# Sqlite3 ORM for C++ implementing lazyloading

Tags: c++, orm, sqlite, cross-platform, lazy-loading

What would you suggest to use in the following scenario:

1. Desktop application in C++
2. Cross platform (might use wxwidgets)
3. Sqlite3 DB (no concurrent accesses by different users)
4. Would like some kind of configurable lazy loading mechanism, meaning certain parts of an object can be loaded at different moments.

I would like to use an ORM to reduce CRUD code, is there any of them that fits the bill?
Do I need to write my own ORM?

Thank you and best regards.

Comment: **Possible Duplicate:**  
[Good ORM for C++ solutions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/74141/good-orm-for-c-solutions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ODB is a C++ ORM released under GPL (or a purchasable commercial license) that supports SQLite. It also supports lazy-loading of relationships and is cross-platform.

See http://www.codesynthesis.com/products/odb/features.xhtml for details.

Answer (score 0):

Qt is an excellent cross-platform development environment, and someone's written [an ORM which goes well with it](http://opensource.bolloretelecom.eu/projects/qdjango/).

Can you elaborate on the requirements for lazy loading?